# 2 cells , which match 2 columns in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to see if 2 cells `C2`, exist in the column `G` and `H` in the same order.

If yes, it will bring back the relevant cell in the F column.

However, it is not working as expected.

I've got this error message `#VALEUR!`

This is the formula I've used

```
 =INDEX(F2:F60000;EQUIV(C2:D2;G1:H60000;0))
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.

I don't think I need VBA but it may be the case, although I hope not.

[image]

Comment: Do a google search for "multi-column vLookup".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via a simple IF Condition like

=IF(C2=G2,IF(D2=H2,F2,"False"))

Comment: Sounds good. I did that `=INDEX(F2:F60000;MATCH(1;(G:G=C2)*(H:H=D2);0))`